# how to get p(words|topic) with lda-ruby

Tags: python, ruby

My algorithm need to calculate `p(words|topic)`.
by Python lda, we can get `p(words|topic)` easily like this

```
>>> print(ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=2, num_words=4))
['0.054*pressur + 0.054*drive + 0.054*brother + 0.054*mother', '0.070*brocolli + 0.070*good + 0.070*health + 0.050*eat']
```

However, with `lda-ruby` gem, print_top_words can only output sorted words (according to topic), but their probability are still unknown:

```
2.2.3 :066 > lda.top_words 2
{
     0 => [
        [0] "i",
        [1] "new"
    ],
     1 => [
        [0] "government",
        [1] "officials"
    ],

    ...

    19 => [
        [0] "i",
        [1] "children"
    ]
}
```

I found top_words is using `lda#beta` to sort words on each topic, beta is a `[topic_num * words_num]` 2D_matrix filled with negative floats, ranging from `-800~0` (approximately), the bigger the floats (close to 0), the higher the words ranked by top_words.

I think I'm close to my object (`get p(words|topic)`), but I don't know how to interpret this beta matrix. It's unlike the other matrix `lda#gamma([doc_num * topic_num]`, filled with positive floats), which can be interpreted as `p(topic|doc)` after normalization, because beta is filled with negatives, and I found no instruction about it yet.

Is there anyone know how to use beta or anything else in `lda-ruby` to get `p(words|topic)`?